# Cordova Tools for VS 2005: iOS app does not display splashscreen and icons

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

Using VS 2013 Cordova Tools (the current version), my iOS app does not display the given splashscreen and icons unless I set `<icon>` and `<splashscreen>` elements in `config.xml`. However, when `config.xml` is edited using the visual editor, it simply deletes all `<icon>` and `<splashscreen>` elements. Am I missing something?

Obs: icons and splash screen works for android apps out of the box, it just does not work for iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a known issue when using the latest version of vs-mda-remote with VS 2013.

You should be able to add this XML to config.xml via Right-Click > View Code to resolve the issue.

```
<platformname="ios">
    <iconsrc="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png"width="180"height="180" />
    <iconsrc="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png"width="60"height="60" />
    <iconsrc="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png"width="120"height="120" />
    <iconsrc="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png"width="76"height="76" />
    <iconsrc="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png"width="152"height="152" />
    <iconsrc="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png"width="40"height="40" />
    <iconsrc="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png"width="80"height="80" />
    <iconsrc="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png"width="57"height="57" />
    <iconsrc="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png"width="114"height="114" />
    <iconsrc="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png"width="72"height="72" />
    <iconsrc="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png"width="144"height="144" />
    <iconsrc="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png"width="29"height="29" />
    <iconsrc="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png"width="58"height="58" />
    <iconsrc="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png"width="50"height="50" />
    <iconsrc="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png"width="100"height="100" />
  </platform>
  <platformname="ios">
    <splashsrc="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"width="320"height="480" />
    <splashsrc="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png"width="640"height="960" />
    <splashsrc="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"width="768"height="1024" />
    <splashsrc="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png"width="1536"height="2048" />
    <splashsrc="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"width="1024"height="768" />
    <splashsrc="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png"width="2048"height="1536" />
    <splashsrc="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png"width="640"height="1136" />
    <splashsrc="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png"width="750"height="1334" />
    <splashsrc="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png"width="1242"height="2208" />
    <splashsrc="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png"width="2208"height="1242" />
  </platform>
```

More known issues: https://www.visualstudio.com/explore/cordova-known-issues-vs

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I simply didn't use graphical config editor and use only text one.

However, the Visual Studio 2015 RC fixes this problem and there is an implicit configuration for every icon and splash screen.